# How can I get a variable by adding strings

Tags: java, variables

I have for example:

```
String invslot_ = "invslot_";
int i = 0;
```

Now I have a `while(i < 44)` loop and I want it
every time it loops to "add" invslot_ and i.
(Yes I could do `invslot_ + i` !)

But I want that `infslot_ + 1` is recognized as a variable I have defined earlier!

I hope you understand what I mean, please answer if you have an idea.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: You are looking for an [`Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: What about putting them into a data structure like Array or List?

Comment: Sounds like you want an array, a collection or a map.

Comment: No idea what you mean, but almost all "I want a `String` to reference a variable name" type questions have the same answer - use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String, Number> vars = new HashMap<>();
vars.put("invslot_1", 3267);

for (int i = 0; i < 44; i++) 
    if (!vars.contains("invslot_" + i))     // put only if "var" is not already "assigned"
        vars.put("invslot_" + i, i);

System.out.println(vars.get("invslot_1"));  // 3267
System.out.println(vars.get("invslot_11")); // 11
```

Comment: Thanks this it what i meant :D